# How does ActiveRecord do data definition transactions with postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, transactions

Are data definition transactions the same as regular transactions?

I want to write a migration that

1. changes table A
2. does some custom data migrations
3. changes table B

Ideally this would all be inside the same transaction. Can I just stick it in an ActiveRecord migration and call it a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each migration is executed within a transaction. From the [Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-are-classes):

> On databases that support transactions with statements that change the schema (such as PostgreSQL or SQLite3), migrations are wrapped in a transaction.

So stick it in a migration and call it a day.

Comment: But is a data definition transaction a different type of transaction? Any quirks for depending on both in the same migration?

Comment: No, they are not different types of transactions, at least not in PostgreSQL. You can do almost anything in one transaction in Postgres (one thing you can't is sequence manipulation -- nextval, setval, etc cannot be rolled back). Try it on a psql command line. `BEGIN`, create a table, insert a row, `ROLLBACK`...

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: Thanks, I've been scanning through the PostgreSQL docs to find a citation that lays it all out, I haven't found it yet though.

Comment: @muistooshort: I think this is documented the other way round: The manual explicitely marks those statements that **cannot** be rolled back (e.g. create database) because "being transactional" is the default not the exception.